# Reusing the same block helper in Meteor causes odd context issue

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm attempting to reuse a custom Block Helper that I wrote to provide basic carousel functionality to some of my templates.

**simple-carousel.html**

```
<template name="SimpleCarousel">
  <div class="simple-carousel {{class}}">
    <div class="slides">
      {{#each slides}}
        {{> UI.contentBlock this}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>
    {{#if showControls}}
      {{> SimpleCarouselControls}}
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="SimpleCarouselControls">
  // control structure here
</template>
```

**simple-carousel.js**

```
var actions = {
  back: function() {
    // move slide back once
  },
  forward: function() {
    // move slide forward once
  }
};

var showSlide = function() {
   // code to show the next slide 
};

Template.SimpleCarousel.onRendered(function() {
  // set up carousel logic here
});

Template.SimpleCarousel.events({
  'click [data-sc-move="forward"]': function() {
      actions.forward();
  },
  'click [data-sc-move="back"]': function() {
      actions.back();
  }
});
```

**breaking_stories.html**

```
<template name="BreakingStories">
  {{#SimpleCarousel class="breaking-stories" showControls=false autoForward=8000 slides=breakingStories}}
    {{> BreakingStorySlide}}
  {{/SimpleCarousel}}
</template>

<template name="BreakingStorySlide">
  <div class="breaking-story slide">
    <div class=breaking-story-title">{{title}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**breaking_stories.js**

```
Template.BreakingStories.helpers({
  breakingStories: function() {
    return BreakingStories.find();
  }
});
```

**daily_summary.html**

```
<template name="DailySummary">
  {{#with thisDailySummary}}
    {{#SimpleCarousel class="daily-summaries" showControls=true slides=items}}
      {{> DailySummarySlide}}
    {{/SimpleCarousel}}
  {{/with}}
</template>

<template name="DailySummarySlide">
  <div class="daily-summary slide">
    <div class="daily-summary-title">{{title}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I've tried to simplify the code as there is a lot more HTML involved in the templates.  Anyway, as you can see I've defined the #SimpleCarousel block helper and used it in two places: the breaking stories section, and the daily summaries section.  These two templates happen to be on the same page (route), so they are near each other on the page.  I need one of them to auto cycle through, in which I've provided the `autoForward` property to the helper, and the other one should just show controls.

Both templates render fine and show the correct data, but the problem lies in that instead of the breaking news template doing any automatic cycling, the other one does (and does it twice), as if they are sharing the same context.

My question is, can I use custom Block Helpers multiple times on the same route safely?  I'm open to any suggestions on how to do this a better/different way.

Comment: What you want to do will be possible, but as you realise, there must be an issue with the components sharing context.  I can't see anything in the code you have above, though I suspect the issue is likely in the code you haven't posted from  simple-carousel.js

Comment: @JeremyK I suspect that may be the case as well, I'll post more of that code tomorrow when I'm back on my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JeremyK for pointing me in the right direction; it happened to be the exact code I left out which was the problem.  Of course!

Here's what I had in the old version:

**simple_carousel.js**

```
var $slideContainer, $controls, $markers, $activeSlide, $nextSlide;

var actions = {
    back: function() {
        // move slide back
    },

    forward: function() {
        // move slide forward
    }
};

function showSlide() {
    // show the "next" slide
}

Template.SimpleCarousel.onRendered(function() {
    var data = this.data;

    $slideContainer = this.$('.sc-slides');
    // rest of this code is irrelevant
});
```

I had thought that the variables I had declared on the first line were independent of multiple instantiations of the templates I was using, but I was wrong.  The first use of `$slideContainer = this.$('.sc-slides');` worked fine, but `$slideContainer` and all the others are shared.

To fix this, I simply moved the local variables/actions into `Template.SimpleCarousel.onRendered`

```
Template.SimpleCarousel.onRendered(function() {
    var $slideContainer, $markers, ...

    this.actions = {
      //...
    };
});

Template.SimpleCarousel.events({
    'click [data-sc-move="forward"]': function( event, template ) {
        template.actions.forward();
    }
    //...
});
```